# Number of possible $7×7$ symmetric matrices such that each row contains numbers from $1$ to $7$.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I've been preparing for quant interviews, and came across this problem.

Problem has 2 parts:

- Number of possible $7×7$ symmetric matrices such that each row contains numbers from $1$ to $7$ (i.e. each row contains all numbers $1$ to $7$ once)
- In extension to that, number of possible matrices where the diagonals contain all numbers $1$ to $7$.

I've been scratching my head for over 3 days now, not even an inch closer since I first started (maybe I'm just stupid).

My paths of approach till now have been to try to observe a pattern from smaller matrices (say $5×5$), for that I fill the matrix row-by-row, but arrive at deadlocks. The two conditions I can immediately realise is that each row and column will have occurrence of a number once (like a crossword puzzle), but there should be something more to avoid the deadlocks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It's about Latin squares. Until now no explicit formula has been found. You can check wiki to know the number.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Apologies, I did not realise that this was looked down upon. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean by "arrive at deadlocks" which you said happened in 5 by 5 case.

Comment: See OEIS [A035481](http://oeis.org/A035481) and [A035482](http://oeis.org/A035482)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start to the problem: in an $n \times n$ symmetric latin square, each number must occur an equal number of times above and below the diagonal. However, for odd $n$ this must imply that each number appears once on the diagonal.